# Table Image Table Alignment Issues

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have a table and inside that table there is a table an image and a table, the first table and second table align on the same line the third and last table is to the right like it should be but on a line under the first table and image. Can someone show me how to align them all on the same line?

```
    <body>

<div id="toptable" align="center">
  <table Style="border:1px solid #FFFF00;"border="0" width="850" id="Nav" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" valign="top">
<td style="width:850 height:60 text-align:center;">
        <table style="float:left;border:5px; border-style:outset;border-color:#E80000; height:20px; width:23%; border-spacing:0; border-collapes:collapse;">
        <tr Style="background-color:#595959;color:FFFF00;">
          <th Style="border:1px solid #FFFF00;font-size:12px; width:45;height:20;"><div style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:-1px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Symbol&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></TH>            
          <th Style="border:1px solid #FFFF00;font-size:12px; width:125;height:20;"><div style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:-1px;">Meaning</div></th>
    </tr>
        <tr> 
      <td style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Not-Scheduled.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></td> 
          <td style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Not Scheduled</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Gray-Astris3.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD>
          <td style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Deactivated Tanks&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Blue-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></td>
      <td style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test Scheduled</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
      <td style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Green-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:22; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></td>
          <td style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test In Process</TD>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
      <td style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Red-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:22; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></td>
          <td style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test Late</td>
        </tr>
   </table>
<div id="pic" align="center">
  <img style="float:none; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:17px; border:10px ridge #E80000; width:199; height:101; " src="../Images/Logo.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="toptable2" align="center">
   <table style="float:right;border:5px; border-style:outset;border-color:#E80000; height:20px; width:23%; border-spacing:0; border-collapes:collapse; vertical-align:top;">
        <tr Style="background-color:#595959;color:FFFF00;">
          <th Style="border:1px solid #FFFF00;font-size:12px; width:125;height:20;"><div style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:-1px;">Meaning</th>
          <th Style="border:1px solid #FFFF00;font-size:12px; width:45;height:20;"><div style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:-1px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Symbol&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
      <tf\d style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Not Scheduled</td>
          <td style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Not-Scheduled.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Deactivated Tanks&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Gray-Astris3.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test Scheduled</td>
          <td style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Blue-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test In Process</td>
          <td style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Green-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:22; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test Late</td>
          <td style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Red-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:22; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></td>
        </tr>
  </table>
    </table>
  </td>
</div>
```

Comment: for starters this is invalid markup.

Comment: @jayharris Whats wrong with it? Or where is it invalid how do I fix it?

Comment: align attribute is not supported in html 5 and depreciated in html 4.01. and html tags are lower cased

Comment: fixed the tags so I should get rid of align attributes and that will fix the problem i'm having?

Comment: 'Java' is to 'JavaScript' as 'Car' is to 'Carpet'.

Comment: @Andrew do you not like my double tag

Comment: Dis/Like has nothing to do with it.  Java has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Nevermind I know what it is sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Tables in HTML are really great deal to manage them. So for better idea of how table works in html follow this link [How to create table in HTML](http://www.edupotpie.com/courses/Learn-Scripting-Language/5/29/Hyper-Text-Markup-language-/1494/How-to-Create-Table?.html)

```
<div id="toptable" align="center">
 <table Style="border:1px solid #FFFF00;"border="0" width="850" id="Nav" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" valign="top">
<td style="width:850 height:60 text-align:center;">
    <table style="float:left;border:5px; border-style:outset;border-color:#E80000; height:20px; width:23%; border-spacing:0; border-collapes:collapse;">
    <TR Style="background-color:#595959;color:FFFF00;">
      <TH Style="border:1px solid #FFFF00;font-size:12px; width:45;height:20;"><div style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:-1px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Symbol&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></TH>            
      <TH Style="border:1px solid #FFFF00;font-size:12px; width:125;height:20;"><div style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:-1px;">Meaning</div></TH>
</TR>
    <TR> 
  <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Not-Scheduled.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD> 
      <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Not Scheduled</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Gray-Astris3.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD>
    <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Deactivated Tanks&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
    <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Blue-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD>
  <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test Scheduled</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR> 
  <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Green-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:22; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD>
      <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test In Process</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR> 
  <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Red-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:22; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD>
      <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test Late</TD>
    </TR>
</table>
 <div id="pic" style="float:left" align="center">
  <img style="float:none; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; margin-top:17px; border:10px ridge #E80000; width:199; height:101; " src="../Images/Logo.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="toptable2" align="center" style='float:left;'>
 <table style="float:right;border:5px; border-style:outset;border-color:#E80000; height:20px; width:23%; border-spacing:0; border-collapes:collapse; vertical-align:top;">
    <TR Style="background-color:#595959;color:FFFF00;">
      <TH Style="border:1px solid #FFFF00;font-size:12px; width:125;height:20;"><div style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:-1px;">Meaning</TH>
      <TH Style="border:1px solid #FFFF00;font-size:12px; width:45;height:20;"><div style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:-1px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Symbol&nbsp;&nbsp;</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR> 
  <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Not Scheduled</TD>
      <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Not-Scheduled.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
  <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Deactivated Tanks&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
  <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Gray-Astris3.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD>
    </TR>
<TR>
  <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test Scheduled</TD>
      <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Blue-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
  <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test In Process</TD>
      <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Green-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:22; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
  <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test Late</TD>
      <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Red-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:22; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD>
    </TR>
  </table>
  </table>
 </td>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets what I want, I just wish I knew why I can't use margin-left/right auto to center the image. I don't like doing it manually this way. Shouldn't I be able to not float the image and then use auto for each margin?

```
 <div id="toptable" align="center">
  <table Style="border:1px solid #FFFF00;"border="0" width="850" id="Nav" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" valign="top">
<td style="width:850 height:60 text-align:center;">
        <table style="float:left;border:5px; border-style:outset;border-color:#E80000; height:20px; width:23%; border-spacing:0; border-collapes:collapse;">
        <TR Style="background-color:#595959;color:FFFF00;">
          <TH Style="border:1px solid #FFFF00;font-size:12px; width:45;height:20;"><div style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:-1px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Symbol&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></TH>            
          <TH Style="border:1px solid #FFFF00;font-size:12px; width:125;height:20;"><div style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:-1px;">Meaning</div></TH>
    </TR>
        <TR> 
      <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Not-Scheduled.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD> 
          <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Not Scheduled</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
      <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Gray-Astris3.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD>
          <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Deactivated Tanks&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
      <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Blue-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD>
      <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test Scheduled</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR> 
      <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Green-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:22; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD>
          <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test In Process</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR> 
      <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Red-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:22; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD>
          <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test Late</TD>
        </TR>
   </table>
<div id="pic" align="center"">
  <img style="float:left; margin-left:120px; margin-right:auto; margin-top:17px; border:10px ridge #E80000; width:199; height:101; " src="../Images/Logo.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="toptable2" align="center"">
   <table style="float:right;border:5px; border-style:outset;border-color:#E80000; height:20px; width:23%; border-spacing:0; border-collapes:collapse; vertical-align:top;">
        <TR Style="background-color:#595959;color:FFFF00;">
          <TH Style="border:1px solid #FFFF00;font-size:12px; width:125;height:20;"><div style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:-1px;">Meaning</TH>
          <TH Style="border:1px solid #FFFF00;font-size:12px; width:45;height:20;"><div style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:-1px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Symbol&nbsp;&nbsp;</TH>
        </TR>
        <TR> 
      <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Not Scheduled</TD>
          <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Not-Scheduled.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
      <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Deactivated Tanks&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD>
      <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Gray-Astris3.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD>
        </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test Scheduled</TD>
          <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Blue-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:25; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
      <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test In Process</TD>
          <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Green-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:22; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
      <TD style="background-color:#000000; color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00; font-family:'Arial'; font-size:12px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Test Late</TD>
          <TD style="background-color:#000000;color:FFFF00; border:1px solid #FFFF00;background-image: url(../Images/Red-Test.png); background-size:22px 24px; width:22; height:24; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;"></TD>
        </TR>
  </table>
    </table>
  </td>
</div>
```